# How to work with break command in nested python loops?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, break

I am completely new to programming and I need some help tonight.  I have a problem I need to solve where I need to prove goldbach's conjecture for a given range of numbers.  I need to make sure the number is even, find out what prime numbers add up to it, print them out and find which number in the range has the greatest number of pairs.   My problem is bellow:

```
for i in range (lower, upper + 1 ):
    if ( pairs > max_pairs):
        max_pairs = pairs
    # Check if Number is Even
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ):
        prime1 = 0
        prime2 = 0
        pairs = 0
        print ( i, "=")
        # Find Prime Numbers less than the Current Even Number
        for x in range ( 2 , ( i  - 1 ) ):
            prime = is_prime ( x )
            if ( prime == False ):
                break
            prime1 = x
            for n in range ( 2, ( i - 1 ) ):
                prime = is_prime (n)
                if ( prime == False ):
                    break
                prime2 = n
                if ( ( prime1 + prime2) == i ):
                    prime_sum = True
                else: 
                    break
                if ( prime1 >= prime2 ):
                    prime3 = prime1
                    prime1 = prime2
                    prime2 = prime3
                if ( prime_sum == True ):
                    print ( prime1, "+", prime2 )
                    pairs += 1
```

I need to get the for loop with the n to repeat if one of those two if conditions is not met, but break sends me back up to the x loop.  How can I get it to repeat if one of those two conditions is false without ending my program?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for adding in the code block.  I thought I did it properly, but clearly I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to use `continue` instead of `break`. If you replace `break` with `continue` in the inner for-loop, then the inner for-loop will restart when prime is `False` or `prime1+prime2 != i`.